Unable to resolve "../components" from "app\index.jsx"
I've been working on developing an app in react native and I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. Anytime I try to pull information from an internal file I get "iOS Bundling failed Unable to resolve [file location] from [requesting file location]". Can someone help me figure out why this is
I've tried running npm start -- --reset-cache, but that didn't work.
This is the code that I have:
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, ScrollView, Image, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'expo-router';
import { CustomButton } from "../components";

const App = () => {

  return (
    <SafeAreaView className='bg-primary h-full'>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{height: '100%'}}>
        <View className='w-full justify-center items-center h-full px-4'>
        <Text className='text-3xl text-white font-bodon text-center'>Be simple.</Text>
        <Link href='/wall' className='text-1xl text-white font-bodon text-center'>Get Started</Link>
        <CustomButton />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App; 

And this is my folder structure:
folder structure

Your file structure is correct and you are basically halfway there. Adjusting the following should do it.
Adjust this
    import { CustomButton } from "../components";

To this
    import { CustomButton } from "../components/CustomButton";


That worked! But now I'm getting an error that says, "TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined." Do you happen to know what caused that? I have nothing in the CustomButton file besides the 'rnfe' format.

In your CustomButton component you will have to export it as default. Then you will have to change this import { CustomButton } from ... to this import CustomButton from ...

You are awesome, thank you so much! I'd upvote this if I could.

You are welcome! You can accept & upvote the original answer :)
